# Apfloat Pi is returning null

Tags: java, scala, nullpointerexception, apfloat

I'm using [the Apfloat library](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) of version [1.8.3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apfloat%7Capfloat%7C1.8.1%7Cjar) 
During my computation i need to calculate value of [pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) with appropriate precision. At the moment i'm using [`ApfloatMath.pi`](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/ApfloatMath.html#pi%28long%29) method and the code looks like this

```
object Problem461 extends App {
  val Pi = ApfloatMath.pi(200)
```

During unit test i'm receiving NullPointerException since [`ApfloatMath.pi`](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/ApfloatMath.html#pi%28long%29) is returning `null`. I have tried many things, set different precisions, including [Apcomplex.DEFAULT](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/Apcomplex.html#DEFAULT), and tried to create [apfloat.properties resource bundle](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/ApfloatContext.html) but result of [`ApfloatMath.pi`](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/docs/org/apfloat/ApfloatMath.html#pi%28long%29) is still `null`.

How i supposed to use this method?

**UPDATE**

I have just solved this issue by declaring `Pi` as `lazy val` :

```
 lazy val Pi = ApfloatMath.pi(100)
```

Also i've made sure `Pi` is calculated correctly as simple `val` during just plain run, not unit test.

So main question changes to:

What could be uninitialized in the [apfloat lib](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) during `val` calculaction at the moment of unit test?